# apscheduler fire every X days at the specific time

Tags: python, python-3.x, apscheduler

I need to make my scheduler fire every X days at the specific time (e.g. every 7 days at 11:30)
my code:

```
def make_interval(record_date: str, record_time: str, record_title: str):
    hours, minutes = _get_hours_minutes(record_time)
    trigger = AndTrigger([IntervalTrigger(days=int(record_date)),
                          CronTrigger(hour=hours, minute=minutes)])
    scheduler.add_job(_send_notification, trigger=trigger,
                      kwargs={...},
                      id=record_title,
                      timezone=user_timezone)
```

but I got error: `[Errno 22] Invalid argument` on the third line.
What's wrong? Can't get why it doesnt work

_get_hours_minutes (just returns separately the value of hours and minutes from "HH:MM")

```
def _get_hours_minutes(user_time: str) -> (str, str):
    return user_time[:2], user_time[3:5]
```

tracebacks:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pizhlo21\Desktop\Folder\python\tg_bot_reminder\scheduler\main.py", line 92, in make_interval
    scheduler.add_job(_send_notification, trigger=trigger,
  File "C:\Users\pizhlo21\Desktop\Folder\python\tg_bot_reminder\venv\Lib\site-packages\apscheduler\schedulers\base.py", line 447, in add_job
    self._real_add_job(job, jobstore, replace_existing)
  File "C:\Users\pizhlo21\Desktop\Folder\python\tg_bot_reminder\venv\Lib\site-packages\apscheduler\schedulers\base.py", line 863, in _real_add_job
    replacements['next_run_time'] = job.trigger.get_next_fire_time(None, now)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pizhlo21\Desktop\Folder\python\tg_bot_reminder\venv\Lib\site-packages\apscheduler\triggers\combining.py", line 55, in get_next_fire_time
    fire_times = [trigger.get_next_fire_time(previous_fire_time, now)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pizhlo21\Desktop\Folder\python\tg_bot_reminder\venv\Lib\site-packages\apscheduler\triggers\combining.py", line 55, in <listcomp>
    fire_times = [trigger.get_next_fire_time(previous_fire_time, now)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pizhlo21\Desktop\Folder\python\tg_bot_reminder\venv\Lib\site-packages\apscheduler\triggers\interval.py", line 68, in get_next_fire_time
    return normalize(next_fire_time)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pizhlo21\Desktop\Folder\python\tg_bot_reminder\venv\Lib\site-packages\apscheduler\util.py", line 431, in normalize
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(dt.timestamp(), dt.tzinfo)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

My OS platform: Windows 10

Comment: What is "_get_hours_minutes"?

Comment: @iohans I edited my question and added code of this function

Comment: Post tracebacks and os platform.

Comment: post version of the apscheduler and Python

Comment: post value of each `record_date: str, record_time: str, record_title: str`

Comment: @NizamMohamed `record_date = '5',  record_type='every_few_days', record_time='11:12'`. all these parameters are taken from the user, so I wrote an example for you. 
versions:
apscheduler 3.9.1
python 3.11.1

Comment: How about `record_title`?

Comment: The `record_title` may have MS Windows filesystem incompatible chars if it's used to store jobs on disk. `Errno 22` is related to filesystem.

Comment: @NizamMohamed `record_title` is also given by user and it can has any value which user prefers

Comment: @NizamMohamed I have another functions which work with another triggers (e.g. 'cron' or 'date') and it work correctly with any value of `record_title`

Comment: Check by passing `record_title` filesystem safe string like "abc"

Comment: @NizamMohamed unfortunately I got the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251181/discussion-between-nizam-mohamed-and-pizhlo).

Comment: Was this issue resolved? I am facing the same issue. One thing, the error is at this line: datetime.fromtimestamp(dt.timestamp(), dt.tzinfo). So there is no point in looking at file names and all.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a closer look at "record_time" and the format that you pass to "_get_hours_minutes". It has to be in the format of "HH:MM" (assuming that the Errno 22 error is for that line. There are other ways to use the datetime library so that you don't have to slice strings.

Comment: i edited my code:

`hours = datetime.strptime(record_time, "%H:%M").hour
minutes = datetime.strptime(record_time, "%H:%M").minute`

but still face this issue `[Errno 22] Invalid argument`

Comment: i guess the problem is not in these lines where I make hours and minutes from the original time. I have another function which works with another trigger and it also contains these lines and everything works correctly